# Roblox bad argument #2 to 'remove' (number expected, got string)

Tags: roblox

Hi im doing a ROBLOX game but my code shows an error

```
players = require(workspace.Players1)
button = script.Parent
player = script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Name

function onMouseButton1Down()
    button.Parent.Visible = false
    table.remove(players,player)
    workspace.Cage1.door.Players.Value = workspace.Cage1.door.Players.Value - 1
end

button.MouseButton1Down:connect(onMouseButton1Down)
```

error: bad argument #2 to 'remove' (number expected, got string)

do anyone knows how to fix it plz?

sorry if im not good at english.

Comment: Hello CesarESP, it's unclear what you are trying to do. Could you explain what you want to happen with your code?

Comment: I have a table with all usernames of players in the game and i would want to remove a user from table when he click a button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you used `table.insert(table, element)` to add all the elements into the first table, the error you are getting is because `table.remove(table, index)` expects a number for the index to remove, not the element itself.
You'll have to iterate over the list to find the element you're looking for.

```
playerList = require(workspace.Players1)
button = script.Parent
playerName = script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Name

function onMouseButton1Down()
    -- hide the button
    button.Parent.Visible = false

    -- remove the player from the list of names
    for i, name in ipairs(playerList) do
        if name == playerName then
            table.remove(playerList, i)
            break
        end
    end

    -- decrease the count of players
    workspace.Cage1.door.Players.Value = 
        workspace.Cage1.door.Players.Value - 1
end

button.MouseButton1Down:Connect(onMouseButton1Down)
```

Answer (score 0):

Additional info to support @Kylaaa's comment

[Removing Items](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/articles/Table)

> An item can be removed from an array with Lua’s table.remove() function. This will remove the item at the specified position and move any following items down one index position.

Example: `table.remove(testArray, 2)`